# React Login page getting focused on 'password' when loading the page instead of 'username'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a login page from react.
This is the input.jsx from which I'm importing the bootstrap components.

```
import React from "react";

const Input = ({ name, label, value, onChange, error }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        autoFocus
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
      />

      {error && <div className="alert alert-danger"> {error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

So now when I call this in main function like this :-

```
<Input
        name="username"
        value={account.username}
        label="Username"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <Input
        name="password"
        value={account.password}
        label="Password"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
```

As I'm first calling for username and then password, so the autofocus property shifts from Username to password.
How to fix this ?
Can't we do something like passing the extra property in prop and then checking it in input file like if focus="true" then applying autofocus else continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two way how it can be fixed

First, one do autoFocus default as false props and pass true for this only for field that should be focused on page:

```
 const Input = ({ name, label, value, onChange, error, autoFocus = false }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
      />

      {error && <div className="alert alert-danger"> {error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

\

```
 <Input
        name="username"
        value={account.username}
        label="Username"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        autoFocus={true}
      />
      <Input
        name="password"
        value={account.password}
        label="Password"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
```

and the second one is to add the possibility to override props inside the input like this and pass autoFocus as false for all inputs that shouldn`t be autoFocused:

```
const Input = ({ name, label, value, onChange, error, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        autoFocus
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        {...props}
      />

      {error && <div className="alert alert-danger"> {error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

\

```
  <Input
        name="username"
        value={account.username}
        label="Username"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <Input
        name="password"
        value={account.password}
        label="Password"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        autoFocus={false}
      />
```

UPD: you just need one input with autoFocus=true at page if you want that this input will be focused